# Getting an specific argument from an list object in Java

Tags: java, list

Don't know if I formulated the question the right way, but here goes...
I need to print the usernames of the objects from the list users.
Here is the User class:

```
public class User {
   public String username;
   public String email;
   public String membership;

   public User (String us, String em, String mm){
       us=username;
       em=email;
       mm=membership;
}}
```

And here is the main class:

```
public class Main {
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    users.add(new User("johnsmith", "johnsmith@gmail.com", "Premium"));
    users.add(new User("walterwhite", "walter.white@gmail.com", "Beginner"));
    users.add(new User("drwho", "doctorwho@gmail.com", "Gold"));
    users.add(new User("parker", "parker2@gmail.com", "Premium"));

    for (int i=0; i<users.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(); // <--------- So I don't know what to use here
}}}
```

What do I use in the println() method? I need to print ONLY the usernames (johnsmith, walterwhite, drwho, parker). Or any other object (email or whatever, I just need to know how to print certain arguments from a list). Already tried println(users.membership), println(membership) and similar variations...

Comment: @Juvanis where exactly encapsulation is broken ?

Comment: @MrPhi OP is using public instance variables and not using getter methods for them. variables should be private.

Comment: @Juvanis and variables should be private, is not it ? There is no sense to use public variable and *eters ?

Comment: I just made the variables public so I spare me the trouble of writing *eters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you want something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
    // Access the user by position in the list
    User user = users.get(i);
    // Now print the username for that specific user
    System.out.println(user.username);
}
```

I've separated the loop body into two statements for clarity, but it's equivalent to:

```
System.out.println(users.get(i).username);
```

This is using the [`List.get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) method to access the item at a particular index in the list.

Now, there are better ways of doing this:

- As noted in comments, the assignments in your constructor are backwards. You need to assign *to* the fields *from* the parameters.
- Your fields should generally be private. Add public "getter" methods where necessary.
- Use the enhanced-for-loop to simply access each element of a collection in sequence:

  ```
  for (User user : users) {
      System.out.println(user.getUserName()); // After addressing the above
  }
  ```

Comment: Even after I make getters, this still returns null. Should I also make setters instead of using a Constructor for that?

Comment: Works fine if you change your constructor. Assignment must be left to right.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(users.get(i).username);
```

I suggest you to use

```
for(Object o : objects)
```

and to declare getters and setters for you fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get()` method with index.

```
for (int i=0; i<users.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(users.get(i).username); // <---get user object at index i and  use here
}
```

And in your constructor, If you closeley look

```
public User (String us, String em, String mm){
       us=username;
       em=email;
       mm=membership;
}
```

Assignment  must be left to right.

That should be

```
public User (String us, String em, String mm){
       username= us;
       email=em;
       membership=mm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your constructor. It should be

```
public User (String us, String em, String mm){
   username = us;
   email = em;
   membership = mm;
```

}

You should probably do some reading on instance variables.